# Display a list as readonly regarless of permission level

Tags: splist

I am currently trying to display a list view outside of its site collection. This has been done using

```
  String str = mySPView.RenderAsHtml();
  Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(str));
```

Since it is outside the site collection, clicking on the list will throw an error.

I tried to set each field to read only but that broke it.

How can I have this set to read only?

UPDATE:
    I am now attempting to retreive the SPListitemCollection & have it autoGenerated in an SPGridView

Answer (score 0):

If you are running outside of your site collection you could for REST with LISTDATA.svc which could be exploited even from a simple CEWP with some Javascript in it.